# .HTACCESS rewrite to index.php?p=home

Tags: html, .htaccess

So I've been using a script for a while though after loosing my files and needing to restart my work, i've come accross one problem.

When a user goes to http://example.com/index.php they use to be redirected to http://example.com/index.php?p=home

Not sure If I have the wrong .HTACCESS or not, but this is what i've got:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?p=home [L]
```

[I also want other pages to work still such as index.php?p=blog]
Also at the moment the only way to get content on the home page is to click a link which goes to index.php?p=home.

Hopefully someone can solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules are only rewriting `example.com` or `example.com/`

You will need to rewrite `example.com/index.php` too:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(index.php)?$ index.php?p=home [L]
```

Any good?

Answer (score 0):

The code you mention does not do that.  To do a simple 301 redirect from one certain page to another simply place this in your VirtualHost file (*not* the .htaccess file)

```
Redirect 301 example.com/index.php example.com/index.php?p=home
```

You can read more about that over [here on the Apache site](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html).

Comment: I'm recieving: SERVER ERROR when using this hmm

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that.  I've updated the answer.  This must go in your vhost file (not the .htaccess)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! Although Lee Kowalkowski [above] answered the question with what I'd want to do it [as a .htaccess] I aprreciate anyways